# "System Monitor" application can't sort, is it a known issue or it's just me?

Tags: 19.04, system-monitor

I tried all combinations of settings and sorted by things such as "% CPU", "ID", "Memory", and no matter what, the values in the sorted column are not sorted in neither direction.
Is it really like that, or could I have broken something?

This is not because of subsequent value changes, the issue happens as soon as I click on a column header to sort it.

Here's an example of sorting by ID which doesn't change anyway.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If i remember it correctly, there is a settings in system monitor to show processes hierarchically (parents/children). If active, It is only order parents then order sub process under them.

Comment: @user.dz yep. I checked and disabled that setting before posting.

Comment: Is this the snap version of System Monitor (pre-installed version is also snap)? If so, what happens if you remove this and use the traditional apt one?

Comment: @pomsky yes, it's preinstalled from snap. and apt version works, thanks for suggestion! if you want you may post an answer and collect the score. if you don't want, I can do it.

Comment: Please go ahead and post an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

(credits for solution to `@pomsky`)

It seems this is because the preinstalled variant of System Monitor is from Snap store, and it just so happens to be poorly made.

If I remove the snap variant and reinstall it from apt

> sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor

then it works without issues.

If I check out reviews for the snap variant in "Ubuntu Software", there are theories that snap packages don't go through QA at all, if that's true then it may be the reason why this happened.